# Initializing new object with random values for each elem in 2D javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this basic iteration and object initialization but it seems like every row is being created with the object containing same ids. Am I getting crazy?

```
function makeGrid (cols, rows) {
  const grid = new Array(cols).fill(new Array(rows))
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = {id: random()}
    }
  }
  return grid
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: How do you know each row is a different object (as opposed to each being a reference to the *same* object)?

Comment: `.fill(new Array(rows))` this is your problem. Use e.g. `.fill().map(_ => new Array(rows));`

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't see the reference problem there. That made it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Scott Hunter and @ASDFGerte (in the comments):
The problem was `new Array(cols).fill(new Array(rows))`. This is filling the newly initiated array with references to another new array `new Array(rows)`. What I wanted to do is creating new arrays for every element in the `cols` array. This solves the issue:

```
[...new Array(cols)].map(() => new Array(rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

this works but is not recommended.  Id's must be unique and using random doesn't guarantee that they will be.

```js
function makeGrid (cols, rows) {
  var grid = new Array(cols)
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
     grid[i] = new Array(rows)      
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      grid[i][j]=  {id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000 )  }  ;
    }
  }
  console.log(grid);
}

makeGrid(3,4)
```

Comment: that was a mock code, IDs don't matter here, that was not the question nor the problem. but thanks!